# The abstract schema type 'User_Book' is unknown

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a database with several entities, in particular `Book` and `User`. Between them there exists a `ManyToMany` relationship like this:

Book:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Book implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name = "bookId", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
  private int price;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "User_Book",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookId"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
  private Set<UserAccount> users;
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserAccounts")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "User_Book",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookId"))
  Set<Book> purchasedBooks;
```

Everything works fine, the table `User_Book` is indeed created in the database. The problem seems to be related to the access of this Table.

For example,

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User_Book u");
```

keeps telling me the following:

> `The abstract schema type 'User_Book' is unknown`

So, shall I create from scratch the `User_Book` entity? Will it get automtically populated like now, that is, whenever a user buys a book, will this purchase be recorded in the table?

Comment: There is no Entity called User_Book. There is a JOIN TABLE called User_Book. You refer to entities in queries, not tables. Define what your query is trying to do

Comment: I just wanted to test whether I was able to access this table from Java perspective.

Comment: you "access the table" by defining a query that uses class/field names, as any JPQL reference would say

Answer (score 0):

User_Book is not an entity. Therefore you cannot use `createQuery`, BUT you can use `createNativeQuery` to execute a SQL query:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM User_Book");
```

The result will be `List<Object[]>`